# In .NET IL is it acceptable to implement an interface's properties and events directly as methods?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil

In my reflective C# code I iterate over the methods on an interface and emit a class that a) is declared as implementing the interface b) has all the methods implemented that `GetMethods()` returns.

```
var methods = typeof(T).GetMethods(); // T is interface
foreach (var methodInfo in methods)
{
    var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray();
    var method = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
        methodInfo.Name,
        MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual,
        methodInfo.ReturnType,
        parameters);
        ... // Emit IL
```

This creates not only the methods but also the properties and events as pairs of methods (get_ set_ / add_ remove_).

The dynamically created class is accepted by the CLR as an implementation of the interface and calling the properties and events on the object (cast as interface) works fine. However in the type builder there is `DefineProperty` as well as `DefineMethod`. Using ildasm I can confirm that '.property' is missing from the declaration if just using `DefineMethod`. Is it naughty to implement an interface's properties and events as if they were 'just' methods? Or is this completely legitimate?

Comment: If you instantiate your new type, assign it to a dynamic `bob` variable and then use `bob.PropertyNameHere` does it work?

Comment: It does not work! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it naughty to implement an interface's properties and events as if
>   they were 'just' methods?

Yes, it is. You won't be able to use properties as properties (when using `dynamic`).

Comment: Half truth, as you can use them as properties, just not when using `dynamic`. None-the-less, I have refactored for purity.

Comment: I wonder, is this behaviour of `dynamic` correct? I have thought that invoking members of `dynamic` should behave just as if I tried to invoke members of the actual most specific type of the object (accessible to the call site).

Comment: If the property isn't properly defined as a property in the IL, I think it is unreasonable to expect that dynamic will be able to treat these 'dodgy properties' like real properties.

Answer (score 2):

It is naughty, and you do not want to do this.

If you do this, your objects may be fine from the point of view of other code invoking them, but they will not be complete from the point of view of reflection. So, your objects will not behave correctly in any situation where proper reflection information is required.

As another answer states, `Dynamic` is an example of such a situation.

<off-topic>

I do not care about `Dynamic` at all. `Dynamic` is:

- a workaround for bad designs, and
- its use leads to irrevocably worse designs.

I understand `Dynamic` is almost everyone's darling nowadays. That's because nowadays almost everyone is a script kiddie.

</off-topic>

But here is a worse problem:

If you try to view your objects in the "Locals" or "Autos" window of the Visual Studio debugger, your generated properties will not appear!  The Visual Studio debugger enumerates the properties of an object in order to decide what to show there, so if your object does not properly define its properties, they will not be shown.

I just encountered this problem with my own stuff and wrote a Question-and-Answer about it:

[Emitted properties do not appear in the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77253623/773113)