# How to emit an interface with properties?

Tags: c#, reflection

I would like to use a TypeBuilder to create an Interface with some properties. I'm trying to modify the accepted solution from the [How to dynamically create a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862226/how-to-dynamically-create-a-class) question.

Here's a sample of the interface that I'd like to create:

```
    public interface ISample
    {
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public double Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the code that I have for creating the Interface:

```
        private static TypeBuilder GetInterfaceTypeBuilder(string TypeName)
        {
            var typeSignature = TypeName;
            var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);

            AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

            ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");

            TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature, TypeAttributes.Interface | TypeAttributes.Abstract);

            return tb;
        }
```

I have tried to create a property like this:

```
        private static void CreateInterfaceProperty(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
        {
            PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
        }
```

This method creates an instance of the Interface type:

```
        public static Type CompileInterfaceType(string TypeName, List<Field> yourListOfFields)
        {
            TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder(TypeName);

            // NOTE: assuming your list contains Field objects with fields FieldName(string) and FieldType(Type)
            foreach (var field in yourListOfFields)
            {
                CreateInterfaceProperty(tb, field.FieldName, field.FieldType);
            }

            Type objectType = tb.CreateType();
            return objectType;
        }
```

The project compiles and runs but when I check the property info for the created instance there are no properties defined.

How do I add a property like the ones shown in ISample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've made a good start in creating the interface dynamically using TypeBuilder. To complete the process and add properties with getters and setters to the interface, you need to define the methods (GetMethod and SetMethod) for each property. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public class Field
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public Type FieldType { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Type dynamicInterfaceType = CompileInterfaceType("ISample", GetSampleFields());
        DisplayProperties(dynamicInterfaceType);
    }

    private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder(string TypeName)
    {
        var typeSignature = TypeName;
        var an = new AssemblyName(typeSignature);

        AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");

        TypeBuilder tb = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeSignature, TypeAttributes.Interface | TypeAttributes.Abstract);

        return tb;
    }

    private static void CreateInterfaceProperty(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
    {
        // Define the property
        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);

        // Define the getter method
        MethodBuilder getMethodBuilder = tb.DefineMethod($"get_{propertyName}", MethodAttributes.Abstract | MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getMethodBuilder);

        // Define the setter method
        MethodBuilder setMethodBuilder = tb.DefineMethod($"set_{propertyName}", MethodAttributes.Abstract | MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, null, new Type[] { propertyType });
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setMethodBuilder);
    }

    private static List<Field> GetSampleFields()
    {
        return new List<Field>
        {
            new Field { FieldName = "Amount", FieldType = typeof(decimal) },
            new Field { FieldName = "Price", FieldType = typeof(decimal) },
            new Field { FieldName = "Quantity", FieldType = typeof(double) }
        };
    }

    private static Type CompileInterfaceType(string TypeName, List<Field> yourListOfFields)
    {
        TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder(TypeName);

        foreach (var field in yourListOfFields)
        {
            CreateInterfaceProperty(tb, field.FieldName, field.FieldType);
        }

        Type objectType = tb.CreateType();
        return objectType;
    }

    private static void DisplayProperties(Type type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Properties of {type.Name}:");
        foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{property.PropertyType} {property.Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides invoking `DefineProperty()`, you also need to define the getter and the setter using the very funnily named methods `SetSetMethod()` and `SetGetMethod()`.

```
MethodBuilder getterBuilder = ...;
MethodBuilder? setterBuilder = ...;
PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty( 
    propertyInfo.Name, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, 
    propertyInfo.PropertyType, null );
propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod( getterBuilder );
if( setterBuilder != null )
    propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod( setterBuilder );
```

As a matter of fact, if you were to only define the getter and the setter, without defining the property, your program would (mostly) work, but you would later run into other problems.  For an explanation of why it is necessary to also define the property, see Stack Overflow: "Emitted properties do not appear in the debugger" [Emitted properties do not appear in the debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77253623/773113)